# Filter out and Break Array into Sub-Array Condition is difference between them is less than or equal to 1

Tags: arrays, swift, sub-array

i am working on an app that has members object list. Now i have to split members into buddies sub array based on their average work speed that is in double type. break members object list into Buddies arrays now in these buddies array add those members which has difference of average work speed less than 1 or equal to for example

i have tired nested loops but the solution is not optimised one.

let array = [2,3,4,6,7,10,9]

resulted subarrays: 
[2,3],[3,4],[6,7],[10,9]

Comment: Your question is very confusing and your result array doesn't seem to have a noticeable pattern. Why there are duplicates of number 3 but not the others.

Comment: 3 is duplicate because it has same difference (1) from 4 and 2 read the condition (difference is equal or less than 1)

context of problem is there are members with random avg work speed we need to create groups of them based on the condition that i mentioned above (1 or less)